# How to redirect to a static (present in file system) 404 error page in DXA 1.5 Java instead of error-404.html

Tags: 2013, 2013-sp1, dxa, dxa-java, dxa-1.5

When a page is not found, the DXA framework initiates a redirect to the website's `error-404.html` page. Instead of that, I want to redirect a static error 404 page which is available in some custom file system path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks @ Tory and Alexey

I am able to override the VIEWS that will be used to show the errors criteria. 
I could create my VIEWS so that they redirect to the appropriate file system error page.

My custom page builder:

```
package com.sdl.modules.nationwide;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import com.sdl.webapp.main.WebAppInitializer;
import com.sdl.webapp.tridion.mapping.PageBuilder;
import com.sdl.webapp.common.api.content.ContentProvider;
import com.sdl.webapp.common.api.content.ContentProviderException;
import com.sdl.webapp.common.api.localization.Localization;
import com.sdl.webapp.common.api.model.PageModel;
import com.sdl.webapp.common.api.model.mvcdata.MvcDataCreator;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
@Component
public class CustomPageBuilder implements PageBuilder{

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebAppInitializer.class);

      @Override
      public PageModel createPage(org.dd4t.contentmodel.Page genericPage, PageModel pageModel, Localization localization,
            ContentProvider contentProvider) throws ContentProviderException {
            LOG.debug("CustomPageBuilder::createPage checking pageModel name: {}", pageModel.getName());
            if (pageModel.getName().contains("_Error Page Not Found")) {
                  pageModel.setMvcData(MvcDataCreator.creator().fromQualifiedName("ViewsRootFolderName:NotFoundViewName").create());
            }
            return pageModel;
      }
      @Override
      public int getOrder() {
            return 1000;
      }
}
```

**In Error404.jsp:**

```
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="dxa" uri="http://www.sdl.com/tridion-dxa"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="nw" uri="/WEB-INF/tld/NationwideTagLibrary.tld"%>

<%
    RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher; 
    requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/testfolder/error404.jsp");
    requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);   
%>
```

Answer (score 6):

In case of 404 exception DXA indeed resolves a page `error-404` and shows it. Such a case is handled by `@ExceptionHandler(NotFoundException.class)` annotation in `PageController`. I don't see any way how to override it properly.

Fortunately, you have `MvcData` and ability to write your custom `PageBuilder`. Make sure that your builder is executed after default one (`order > Integer.MIN_VALUE`), and is a Spring Bean (e.g. annotated by `@Component`). Check in it if a page name or title has special marker (use any constant marker you like) and substitute page's `MvcData`.

```
@Override
public <T extends PageModel> T createPage(Page genericPage, T pageModel, Localization localization, ContentProvider contentProvider) throws ContentProviderException {
    if (pageModel.getName().contains("_Error Page Not Found")) {
        pageModel.setMvcData(MvcDataCreator.creator().fromQualifiedName("Core:NotFound").create());
    }
    return pageModel;
}
```

`PageController` will then resolve this `MvcData` into `Core/Page/NotFound` meaning that you now can place your view under this `Area/Region/View`.

Play with different values of `MvcData` to get view resolved from your module.