# How to redirect to a static 404 error page, When we did custom static folder path request filter based on the request path in DXA 1.5 (Java)

Tags: 2013-sp1, web8, dxa, dxa-java, dxa-1.5

How to redirect to a static (present in the file system) 404 error page in DXA 1.5 (Java), When we did custom static folder path request filter based on the request path (Ex: http://localhost:9080/cp/test/fafd) in DXA 1.5 (Java)

```
/*  Ex - in core.json 
   "existingPaths":"/css/,/cp/,/media/,/components/"
*/
```

As per my client requrement, We have implemneted the static file path request filter based on the request path (Ex: http://localhost:9080/cp/test/fafd) it shoud show custom error 404 page which is available in file system but it's showing blank screen

The scope of the implementation is; if any of the request path match with the `"existingPaths" in core.json` those request will not check the pages in Broker DB. the static request filter is working fine but when I request invalid path it's showing blank screen instead of custom 404 page

our implementation in `com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.localization`:

```
public class LocalizationImpl implements Localization
{
//...

    /* We have implemented the static folder request filter based on the request path after domain (Ex: )
        // Ex - in core.json 
       "existingPaths":"/css/,/cp/,/media/,/components/"
    */

    public boolean isStaticContent(String url)
       {
            if (!url.startsWith(path)) {
               return false;
             }
             if (url.startsWith(mediaRoot)) {
              return true;
           }

        int endIndex = url.indexOf("/", url.indexOf("/") + 1);
         if (endIndex > 0) {
          String folderPath = url.substring(0, endIndex + 1);
           List<String> existingPaths = getExistingPath();
           if (existingPaths.contains(folderPath)) {
            LOG.trace("LocalizationImpl: isStaticContent : folderPath - {} ", folderPath);
             return true;
           }
         }

        String p = path.equals("/") ? url : url.substring(path.length());
        return (p.equals("/favicon.ico")) || (SYSTEM_ASSETS_PATTERN.matcher(p).matches());
   }

    public List<String> getExistingPath()
       {
        String[] straExistingPath = getConfiguration("core.existingPaths").split("(\\s*)?,(\\s*)?");

        List<String> listExistingPath = Arrays.asList(straExistingPath);
         return listExistingPath;
       }

//...

}
```

The related implementation reference  - [How to redirect to a static (present in file system) 404 error page in DXA 1.5 Java instead of error-404.html](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/17395/how-to-redirect-to-a-static-present-in-file-system-404-error-page-in-dxa-1-5-j)

I'm getting the blank screen when I request invalid page: EX-
[image]